# Getting information about hardware configuration

Tags: c#, wmi, gpu

I'm interested in getting information of hardware configuration using C#. To do this I use WMI and it's too easy for most of parameters required to me.
But it's impossible to get bus width parameter using WMI.
Is there any ways to do this?
Or, maybe there is some free libraries or another ways?

[image: Bus width of my video card using GPU-Z]

Comment: This may help you. I haven't tried though. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394486(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly I'm looking for. Using this class I'm able to detect the next property (closest to bus width):

 "...The MaxDataWidth property returns the maximum bus width of adapter cards that can be inserted into this slot, in bits...". 

But an actual bus width can be another.
So, question still open.